# Very long resumption of internet access

Tags: android, http

Generally I use this code to get some data from web-server:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
String url = "http://someurl.url";
HttpResponse resp = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
```

Problem is that when I turn off network and then turn it on, the process of getting of responce takes more than one minute, whilst other applications can get data from internet more faster.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use something like that? I think that can be good because you specify the time out.

```
try {
   URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
   HttpURLConnection urlConnect = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   urlConnect.setConnectTimeout(1000);
   urlConnect.getContent();
   System.out.println("Connection established.");
} catch (NullPointerException np) {
    np.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException io) {
    io.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if it is the same request being done for the second time.they might be hitting the client side cache memory.